# Annoying general behavior: the width of the text-input-fields, when editing a node, can be up to 2X your screen's width / decentered

Tags: nodes

I was just wondering whether anyone else is annoyed by the curious & sporadic behavior of Drupal of making the widths of the text-input-fields very large, when starting to edit a node.

The widths of the **text-input-fields** (by default: "**Body**" & "**Summary**") get as much as 2 times the width of my computer screen.

Would anyone know how to get under the hood, to try and come up with a fix?

I am also not sure about the origin of the behavior, which sometimes does show up; and at other times don't.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds as if you are talking about WYSIWYG editor; which module are you using - WYSIWYG, CKEditor or something else?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen What admin theme are you using?

Comment: @Topsitemakers I'm not using any editor, but edit the nodes directly via Drupal's admin theme. My default theme is a custom *Bootstrap* & my administration theme is **Seven**. I mainly use Firefox 37. It might very well be a browser-related issue. In Chrome & Safari, the problem isn't appearing on the first trials.

Comment: @J.Reynolds Changing e.g. to **Stark** keeps the same issue. However: changing to other admin themes does appear to **change** the issue, but *not entirely resolve* it. All the other themes which I have tried, still show a **similar** issue (now both in Firefox & Chrome): now the text-fields have a good width, but everything (the GUI-panels containing the text-fields) is shifted to the right. This is at least an improvement, since it requires only 1 mouse-action per edit to correct. Thanks.

Comment: @J.Reynolds And then ... after changing the admin theme a couple of times: now the ISSUE IS RESOLVED, NO MATTER WHAT ADMINISTRATION THEME ONE CHOOSES. =) Good, but strange news. If you would like, you can post an answer, saying: just fiddle around by changing the admin themes & the issue might be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the adept question by @[J.Reynolds](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/26511/j-reynolds)

Might solve this issue: (did so for me)

## Just change the administration theme a couple of times

This can be changed at **Appearance >> Administration**

- To which you can navigate manually using the administrative overlay
- Or to which you can arrive directly, by default, via **www.Your-Website-Domain**`/#overlay=admin/appearance`